# Tests run fine in Eclipse, but fails to execute in Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins

I have written tests in Selenium(java) and i am using testNG framework. When i run the selenium scripts, everything works fine but when i try to run it through Jenkins. Chrome Webdriver doesnot open and tests are running in Background and moreover some elements are not interactable when tests run through jenkins and the tests fail but everything works fine they are run i eclipse.

1. I have tried allowing Jenkins as a service to interacting with desktop. I changed some configuration. Services > Jenkins > jenkins properties>log on > (tick) Allow service to interact with desktop.

   2. I have also tried Webdriver wait, for making elements to wait untill the element is clickable. But that fails too.

   This is my test class. Test with priority 3 always fails.

```java
package multipleclass.multipleclass; 

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class AaaTest extends BaseTest {
    public WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void setExtent(){

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Automation Testing\\chromedriver.exe");  
        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.get("localhost:4200");

    }


    @Test(priority =1)
    public void Open_AppianRx() {
        test = extent.createTest("SCENARIO 1");
        String title =driver.getTitle();
        Assert.assertEquals(title,"AppianRx");
    }

    @Test(priority =2, dependsOnMethods = "Open_AppianRx")
    public void AppianRx_SignIn() throws InterruptedException {

        Thread.sleep(500);
        driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();
        //Handling the Sign In window 
        String ParentDriver=driver.getWindowHandle();
        Set<String> Windows=driver.getWindowHandles();
        int numberOfWindows = Windows.size();

        if(numberOfWindows==2) 

            for(String handle: Windows) 
            {
                if(!handle.equals(ParentDriver)) {
                    driver.switchTo().window(handle);
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    driver.manage().window();
                }        
            }

        Thread.sleep(100);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"i0116\"]")).sendKeys("ashutosh@XXXXx.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'idSIButton9\']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("i0118")).sendKeys("XXXXXXX");
        Thread.sleep(100);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'idSIButton9\']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);

        //Passing Control to Pop-up
        String bhandle = driver.getWindowHandles().toArray()[1].toString();
        driver.switchTo().window(bhandle);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"tilesHolder\"]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/small")).click();                

        driver.switchTo().window(ParentDriver);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    @Test(priority =3, dependsOnMethods = "AppianRx_SignIn")
    public void Open_CaseList() throws InterruptedException {

        Thread.sleep(1000);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"m_ver_menu\"]/ul/li[4]/a/span")).click();  //*[@id="m_ver_menu"]/ul/li[4]/a/span
        Thread.sleep(100);
        //String title= driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/m-pages/div/div/div/m-case-view/mat-card[1]")).getText();
        //Assert.assertEquals(title,"Case List");
    }

    @Test(priority =4, dependsOnMethods = "Open_CaseList")
    public void Open_AddNewCaseScreen() throws InterruptedException {

        Thread.sleep(1000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("createCae")).click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
         String title= driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/m-pages/div/div/div/m-case-create/mat-card")).getText();
        Assert.assertEquals(title,"Create Case");
    }
    @Test(priority =5, dependsOnMethods = "Open_AddNewCaseScreen")
    public void Case_Create() throws InterruptedException {

        //Case Reference  
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='mat-select-1']/div/div[1]/span")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("mat-option-5")).click();//HCP
        Thread.sleep(200);
        //Contact Method
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"mat-select-2\"]/div/div[1]/span")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("mat-option-7")).click();//Call Received
        Thread.sleep(200);
        //Enrollment Type
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"mat-select-3\"]/div/div[1]/span")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("mat-option-8")).click();//Reimbursement
        Thread.sleep(200);
        //Product
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"mat-select-4\"]/div/div[1]/span")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("mat-option-11")).click(); 
        Thread.sleep(200);
        //Preferred Pharmacy
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"mat-select-5\"]/div/div[1]/span")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("mat-option-13")).click(); 
        Thread.sleep(200);
        //Contact Signature
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"mat-select-6\"]/div/div[1]/span")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("mat-option-15")).click();//Yes
        Thread.sleep(200);
        //Buy & Bill
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"mat-select-7\"]/div/div[1]/span")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("mat-option-16")).click();//No
        Thread.sleep(200);
        //SAVE & NEXT
        driver.findElement(By.id("saveAndNext")).click();

    }

    @Test(priority =6, dependsOnMethods = "Case_Create")
    public void Fax_Notification() throws InterruptedException {

        Thread.sleep(1000) ;
        //Physician Name
        driver.findElement(By.id("mat-input-14")).sendKeys("Name of Physician");
        //Location Name
        driver.findElement(By.id("mat-input-15")).sendKeys("Location Name");
        //Location Address
        driver.findElement(By.id("mat-input-16")).sendKeys("Location Address");
        //Location Phone
        driver.findElement(By.id("mat-input-17")).sendKeys("Location Address");
        //Skip Notification
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'skipNotification\']/span")).click();

    }

}
```

I expect the tests to run fine when are run through jenkins as they do in eclipse but they dont. Jenkins is not able to open chrome and is running tests in the background.

Comment: Are you running it on slave? What OS is installed on the executor machine? What's agent configuration? Are the agent is being run as a service?

Comment: Please add the errors you get. I think that the problem is that you rely only on `sleep` to wait for elements. The durations are well suited for your local environment but not necessarily for other machines, where it may take more time to load the elements. Personally I use to wait for an element to be visible / clickable instead of just waiting for a specific amount of time.

Comment: @Dubilyer  No i am not running it on slave. I am running it on master. Os is windows   10. i have extracted jenkins through a .war file.

Comment: @AshutoshRaghuwanshi after you changed the Jenkins configuration 'Services > Jenkins > jenkins properties>log on > (tick) Allow service to interact with desktop' did you restart the service? (It should be restarted to take effect)

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel  Failed tests : Open_Caselist(multipleclass.multipleclass.AaaTest): element not interactable(...). I have tried using webdriver wait for the particular element but it's still not interactable.   
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait (driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityofElementLocated(By.xpath("  ")));